# My External JavaScript files stopped working after successful ajax call to reload a div

Tags: php, html, jquery

I'm building a simple chat system using Ajax, jQuery, PHP, MySQLi.

On the chatting page, jquery post request is set to handle user sent messages.
Now the problem is, when I sends a message to a user, the message will be sent successfully, on trying to update the div (chat messages), some of my externally included js files in the index page will stop working. See **jQuery** code below:

```
$(function(){
$("#send-msgs").click(function(e){

/* Auto Detect A Link  (START)*/

// Get the content
var output = $("#message").val();
var chat_id = $("#chat_id").val();
e.preventDefault();

//Start Post Request
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post_message.php",
    data: "message_text="+output+"&chat_id="+chat_id,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
        //Show Events before sending request
        $(".chat-main .active .details h6").html("<span class='text-primary'>You: </span><span class='text-secondary'>Sending...");
        $(".chat-main .active .date-status h6#time_status").html("--:-- --");
        $(".chat-main .active .date-status h6#msg_status").html("<span title='Sending...' class='fa fa-ellipsis-h'></span>");
        $("#setemoj").attr({
            "disabled" : "disabled",
        });
        $("#send-msg").attr({
            "disabled" : "disabled",
        });
    },
    //If everything looks right, continue
    success: function(response){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "only_load_chat.php",
            data: "phone_number=<?php echo @$phone_number1;?>&chat_id="+chat_id,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                // alert(response);
                var current_time = $("#js_current_time").val();
                var msg = $("#setemoj").val();
                $(".chat-main .active .details h6").html("<span class='text-primary'><b>You:</b> </span><span class='text-secondary'>"+output+"</span>");
                $(".chat-main .active .date-status h6#time_status").html(current_time);
                $(".chat-main .active .date-status h6#msg_status").html("<span title='Seen'><span title='Sent' class='fa fa-check text-primary'></span></span>");
                // $(".chat-main .active .details .date-status h6").html(js_current_time);
                $("#fetch_chat").html(response);
                document.getElementById("setemoj").removeAttribute("disabled");
                document.getElementById("setemoj").value = "";
            },
        })
    }
});
});
```

});

**post_message.php file**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
session_start();
require "./includes/db-config.php";
require "./includes/check_if_login.php";
require "./includes/SaNiTiZer.php";
require "./includes/function.php";
if(isset($_REQUEST['chat_id']) && isset($_REQUEST['message_text'])){

    $user_msg  = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['message_text']);
    $chat_id1 = $_REQUEST['chat_id'];

    $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO direct_chats_msg(`message`, `user_id`, chat_id) VALUES(?,?,?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 'sii', $user_msg, $user_id, $chat_id1);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
    echo "Done";
} else {
    echo "Error in POST request";
}
} else {
    echo "Error in POST request";
}
```

**only_load_chat.php**

```
 <?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    session_start();
    require "./includes/db-config.php";
    require "./includes/check_if_login.php";
    require "./includes/SaNiTiZer.php";
    require "./includes/settings.php";
    require "./includes/function.php";

$phone_number1 = $_REQUEST['phone_number'];
$main_chat_id = $_REQUEST['chat_id'];
?>

                    <!--<script src="./assets/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>-->
                    <!--<script src="./assets/js/tippy-bundle.iife.min.js"></script>-->
                    <!--<script src="./assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>-->
                    <!--<script src="./assets/js/switchery.js"></script>-->
                    <!-- <script src="./assets/js/easytimer.min.js"></script> -->
                    <!-- <script src="./assets/js/index.js"></script> -->
                    <!-- <script src="./assets/js/popper.min.js"></script> -->
                    <!-- <script src="./assets/js/feather-icon/feather.min.js"></script>-->
                    <!-- <script src="./assets/js/feather-icon/feather-icon.js"></script>-->
                    <!-- <script src="./assets/js/zoom-gallery.js"></script> -->
                    <!-- <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script> -->

                    <ul class="chatappend">
    <?php

        $sql = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * from direct_chats_msg where chat_id=?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 'i', $main_chat_id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);

        $get_result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($get_result)>0){
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($get_result)){
                $sender = $row2['user_id'];

                $sql2 = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT id, userID, FirstName, LastName, OtherName, DisplayName, reg_date, 
                about_text, profile_pic, gender, countryCode, phone_number, `address`, `state`, country, website, is_online from accounts where id=?");
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql2, 'i', $sender);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($sql2);

                $get_result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($sql2);
                    $row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($get_result2);
                    $chat_msg_id = $row2['dcm_id'];
            ?>
                    <li style="margin:15px;" class="<?php if($row2['user_id']==$user_id){echo"replies";}else{echo"sent";}?>">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="profile mr-4"><img class="bg-img" src="./assets/images/avtar/new/<?php echo $row4['profile_pic'];?>" alt="<?php echo $row4['LastName']." ".$row4['FirstName'];?>" /></div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <div class="contact-name">
                                    <!-- <h5><?php echo $row4['LastName']." ".$row4['FirstName'];?></h5> -->
                                    <h6><?php echo date("h:i:s A", strtotime($row2['chat_time']));?></h6>
                                    <ul class="msg-box">
                                        <li class="msg-setting-main">
                                            <div class="msg-dropdown-main">
                                                <div class="msg-setting"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h"></i></div>
                                                <div class="msg-dropdown" style="box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);margin-top:-15px;margin-left:-100px;">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share"></i>forward</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clone"></i>copy</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>rating</a></li>
                                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="ti-trash"></i>delete</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <h5 class="msg-content" id="msg-content<?php echo $row2['dcm_id'];?>" style="<?php if($row2['user_id']==$user_id){echo"background-color:#1c9dea;color:#ffffff;padding:7px;";}else{echo"background-color:#e5edf5;color:#000;padding:7px;";}?>">
                                            <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($row2['message']);?><br/>
                                            </h5>
                                        </li>
                                        <div id="link_title<?php echo $chat_msg_id;?>"></div>
                                            <!--</li>-->

                                            <style>
                                                .custom_emoji {
                                                    width: 20px;
                                                    height: 20px;
                                                    background-origin: content-box;
                                                    color: transparent;
                                                    text-align: center;
                                                    padding: 3px;
                                                }

                                                .msg-content a {
                                                    color: #FF9800;
                                                    text-decoration: none;
                                                    border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
                                                }
                                                .msg-content a:hover { color: #ffffff; }
                                            </style>
                                        </li>

                                        <!-- <script>
                                            function newMesssage() {
                                                    var message = $('.message-input input').val();
                                                    if($.trim(message) == '') {
                                                        return false;
                                                    }
                                                    // var today = new Date(),
                                                    //     h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
                                                    //     m = checkTime(today.getMinutes()),
                                                    //     s = checkTime(today.getSeconds());
                                                    // document.getElementById('cur_time').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

                                                    var current_time = $("#js_current_time").val();
                                                    $('<li class="replies" style="margin:15px;">\
                                                    <div class="media"> \
                                                    <div class="profile mr-4 bg-size" style="background-image: \
                                                    url(&quot;./assets/images/avtar/new/<?php // echo $profile_pic;?>&quot;); background-size: \
                                                    cover; background-position: center center;"></div>\<div class="media-body">\
                                                    <div class="contact-name"> <h5>  </h5> <h6 id="cur_time">'+current_time+'</h6> \
                                                    <ul class="msg-box"> <li> <h5 style=background-color:#1c9dea;color:#ffffff;padding:7px;>\
                                                    ' + message + '</h5> </li></ul> </div></div></div></li>').appendTo($('.messages .chatappend'));
                                                    $('.message-input input').val(null);
                                                    $('.chat-main .active .details h6').html('<span>You: </span>' + message);
                                                    $(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
                                                };

                                        </script> -->
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php require "./includes/current_user_chat_profile(right_sidebar).php";?>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
                </ul>

            <?php
    } else {?>
    <!-- node.js -->
            <?php require "./includes/current_user_chat_profile(right_sidebar).php";?>

            <script src="./assets/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>
            <script src="./assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./assets/js/tippy-bundle.iife.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="./assets/js/switchery.js"></script>
            <script src="./assets/js/easytimer.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./assets/js/index.js"></script>
            <script src="./assets/js/feather-icon/feather.min.js"></script>
            <script src="./assets/js/feather-icon/feather-icon.js"></script>
            <script src="./assets/js/zoom-gallery.js"></script>
            <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
    <?php
    }
 } else {
        require "./includes/error.php";
     }
//  } else {
//     require "./includes/error.php";
// }
?>
```

The externally included js files in the **only_load_chat.php**, when the comments are removed it would make the included js files in the index page not to work (But making the page load too slow), Even after viewing the codes via the developer mode (Ctrl+Shift+I Key), I will be seeing duplicates of the js files.

Please can someone help with me this:
I don't want the externally included js files in the index page disabled, because when disabled, that would make me to include the js files it in the **only_load_chat.php**, as this would make the website load very slow.

Thanks

Comment: Your `only_load_chat` should only load the HTML that's required to get the chat response and nothing else.  Any `script` should have already been loaded in the main page.  The issue with "javascript files not working" is, possibly, more likely reworded as "events from external files not working" - and it's *possible* that this is because you are overwriting / recreating the HTML that those events apply to.   Try changing all your events to event delegation - instead of `$("#fetch_chat").click(function() { ...` change to `$(document).on("click", "#fetch_chat", function() { ...`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for you help. I tried what you said by using `$(document).on("click", "#fetch_chat", function() { ...` but its still not working.